# Matrix column is still in "character" class after applying as.numeric

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

```
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyr)
prices_hwpj <- tq_get(c("APPL","MSFT"),
                 from = "2015-01-01",
                 to = "2020-01-01",
                 get = "stock.prices",
               )
prices_hwpj <- as.matrix(prices_hwpj)
prices_hwpj <- as.matrix(prices_hwpj[,c(1,2,8)])
prices_hwpj[,3] <- as.numeric(prices_hwpj[,3])

typeof(prices_hwpj[1,3])
class(prices_hwpj[1,3])
```

The data is a tibble before converted to a matrix. All the elements are character.

I tried to convert the 3rd column from character to numeric. But the above code doesn't work. Result of class/type is still character. Why is that?

Comment: All columns of a matrix _must_ be the same class.

Comment: `prices_hwpj` is already a tibble where 3rd column is of type numeric why do you need to convert it into matrix?

Answer (score 0):

```
prices_hwpj <- tq_get(c("APPL","MSFT"),
                      from = "2015-01-01",
                      to = "2020-01-01",
                      get = "stock.prices",
)

prices_hwpj <- as.matrix(prices_hwpj)
prices_hwpj <- as.matrix(prices_hwpj[,c(1,2,3,8)])
prices_hwpj_value_in_a_matrix <- matrix(nrow = length(prices_hwpj[,3]), ncol =4)
prices_hwpj_value_in_a_matrix[,3]<- as.numeric(prices_hwpj[,3])
typeof(prices_hwpj_value_in_a_matrix)
class(prices_hwpj_value_in_a_matrix)
prices_hwpj_have_to_be_same_lenght <- rbind(prices_hwpj,prices_hwpj_value_in_a_matrix)
typeof(prices_hwpj_have_to_be_same_lenght)
class(prices_hwpj_have_to_be_same_lenght)
```

Matrix have to be the same lenght to `rbind`, type `double`is floating point,so what I did is create a empty matrix with same lenght of colum of final result and same rows number as the  `prices_hwpj`.